# Trying to add the occurance of a letter in an array

Tags: java

so what im doing is creating a program that reads in 2 text files, 1 is a plain text file the other is an encrypted version of the text file.

I set the String (for every line) to uppercase and i take the char of the String index 0-65 thats where i get my position in the array.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   public class ReadIn {
public void fileReader(){
try{
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("plaintext.txt"));
    //Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("ciphertext.txt"));
    int lol[] = new int[27];
    while(inFile1.hasNextLine()){
        String base = inFile1.nextLine();
        base.toUpperCase();
        String placeHolder = base;
        for(int i=0;i<base.length();i++){
            if(placeHolder.charAt(0)==' '){}
            else if(base.charAt(0)=='.'){}else if(base.charAt(0)==','){}
            else if(base.charAt(0)=='"'){}else if(base.charAt(0)==':'){}
            else if(base.charAt(0)=='-'){}else if(base.charAt(0)=='?'){}
            else if(base.charAt(0)=='!'){}else{lol[(base.charAt(0)-65)]++;}
            placeHolder = placeHolder.substring(1);
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<lol.length;j++){
        System.out.println(lol[j]);
        //To show what is inside the Index.
    }

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File is not in the correct directory!");
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Array Index is to small!!");
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output i get when i set the array size to 60

> 142 119 0 0 0 62 60 0 682 0 0 179 24 232 0 62 0 0 0 184 0 0 440 0 63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 471 182 215 94 60 409 0 242 174 15 30 62 273 79 405 189 0 195 472 673 101 62 324 0 124 0 0 0

The question is, when I run the program, why is my array to small. If all letters are capitalized, then subtracting 65 from a char such as 'A' should be 0 and therefor add 1 to index [0] in the array.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

update

OK so i set the string to capitalize it self by "base = base = base.toUpperCase();"
This worked flawlessly except that my array has to be set at 91 to compensate for the Z (90) in ascii
when i try to go to the index point of the array to add i use [(base.charAt(0)-65)]++
but it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -21

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, The question is, when i run the program why is my array to small. if all letters are capitalized, then subtracting 65 from a char such as 'A' should be 0 and there for add 1 to index [0] in the array.

Comment: What do you mean that your array is too small? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: You should probably not catch `FileNotFoundException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. By doing so, you are ignoring some critical information from the stacktrace which will help you (and us) figure out the problem with your code.

Comment: Did you really code `base = base = base.toUpperCase();`?  If so, why?

Comment: (Oh, I see -- you're over-compensating for your previous sin of `base.toUpperCase();` with no receiver.)

Comment: that was a typo it was meant to be base=base.ToUpperCase();

Comment: So the faulty index is `-21`? That would mean `base.charAt(0)` was `44`, which corresponds to a comma `,`. This would mean that either your filtering is not working correctly, or your input is malformed. Can try putting a `System.out.println(base.charAt(0))` in that `else` block to see if you're getting the right type of characters?

Comment: Your right that was the problem, i removed all the commas, but i was curious if there is a way to remove it in the program

Comment: @Loligans Surely you can do that programmatically, but I cannot make sense out of your program and with no sample input and output, I cannot suggest what is actually wrong with it.

Comment: I ended up doing that, it now indexes all the characters in the alphabet correctly, what i don't understand is why the ',' wasn't caught in the if statement, but the space was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `base` still contains lowercase characters, as you're not using the return value of `toUpperCase()`. This is confirmed by your test data: your output spans the ASCII range from 65 (`A`) to 122 (`z`), counting 58 different character codes.

Strings in Java are immutable, their value does not change after they are constructed. Therefore, `base.toUpperCase()` returns a *new string* and does not modify the original `base` string. You want to replace `base` by its capitalized version, therefore you should override its value so it points to the returned string:

```
base = base.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: @millimoose Damnit, you're right. Totally missing the ball here. Fixing!

Comment: This worked for me, i edited my main post, with a new error that is being thrown

Comment: Alright so the problem was there was punctuation in the text file which was throwing array index out of bounds because when i subtracted 65 it put it in a negative index which threw the exception.